# how to track time spend on time

Tags: php, mysql, user-tracking, visitor-statistic

I want to track the start time  and end time of each page.
I used to below logic but while tracking update query slow down our website.Please give solution how to decrease the server load time

```
$sql_check = "
   SELECT uniquevisitorid 
   FROM analytics.tbl_analytics_data 
   WHERE uniquevisitorid = '".$strca[1]."'";
    $analycz = mysql_query($sql_check,$comp_con);
if(mysql_num_rows($analycz)<1){
        $unix_start_time = strtotime(date('jS F Y h:i:s A (T)'));
        $unix_end_time   = '';
    }
    else
    {
        $unix_start_time = strtotime(date('jS F Y h:i:s A (T)'));
        $unix_end_time = $unix_start_time;

        $update_analycz="
           UPDATE analytics.tbl_analytics_data  
           SET unixtimestamp_end = '".$unix_start_time."' 
           WHERE uniquevisitorid='".$strca[1]."'  
           ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;";
        $result = mysql_query($update_analycz,$comp_con);
    }
```

for inserting data used below insert query

```
$insert_into_analycz="
   INSERT INTO analytics.tbl_analytics_data  (cookiename,domainhash,uniquevisitorid,unixtimestamp_start,unixtimestamp_end,sessionid,session_counter,referral,path,domainname,userip,country,city,browser,useros,querystring,http_host,http_user_agent,inserttime) 
  VALUES('','".$strca[0]."','".
 $strca[1]."','".
$unix_start_time."','','".
$trace_info['session_id']."','".
$trace_info['sc']."','".
$trace_info['referer']."','".
$trace_info['path']."','".
$dn."','".
$trace_info['user_ip']."','".
$trace_info['UserCountry']."','".
$trace_info['UserCity']."','".
$trace_info['UserBrower']."','".
$trace_info['UserOS']."','".
$trace_info['UserQuery_String']."','".
$trace_info['JDHTTP_HOST']."','".
$trace_info['user_agent']."',now())";
```

Comment: You could try saving the data in session at the start and updating it once it leaves your page with ajax using onunload. Also be careful with unescaped values in your query and try to avoid deprecated extensions (mysql_query).

Comment: Please stop using mysql_* functions as they are deprecated - http://php.net/mysql_connect.  The mysqli_* functions are your friend now - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

Comment: PHP? For more precision, use `microtime(true)`.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you have to start your timer before your query mysql and end after.

```js
//BEFORE
$analycz = mysql_query($sql_check,$comp_con);
//AFTER
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not to use mysql.

Use standard log file.

and create couple stat pages that will parse the log file and show the results you need and/or insert data from the log file into sql table.